# Show that $\text{Sq}(A) \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Synopsis**

With this exercise, I've figured out a crucial error in my solution that I'm not sure how to fix. I would greatly appreciate any tips or hints that might help me figure it out.

**Exercise**

Assume that $A$ is a set with at least two elements. Show that $\text{Sq}(A) \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}A$, where $\text{Sq}(A) = \{f \mid (\exists n \in \omega) \text{$f$ maps $n$ into $A$}\}$.

**Problem**

My effort at a solution went something like this:

Let $f$ be a function in $\text{Sq}(A)$. Define the function $G: \text{Sq}(A) \rightarrow {}^{\omega}A$ as follows:

$$
  G(f)(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
  f(x) & \text{if } x \in \text{dom} f\\
  f(0) & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$

After this, I thought all I had to do was to prove that the following was an injection. However, upon further examination, I found this wasn't the case. For example, consider some $f, f' \in \text{Sq}(A)$ where $f: n \rightarrow A$ and $f': n+1 \rightarrow A$ where for all $x \in n$, $f(x) = f'(x)$  and where $f'(n) = f(0)$. Then $G(f)(x) = G(f')(x)$ and my function isn't injective. How do I fix this?  Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Yah I just realized! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Your basic idea is good, and you’ve correctly found the problem with it. Note that there is an injection $H:\operatorname{Sq}(A)\to\omega\times{}^\omega A$ defined by $H(f)=\langle\operatorname{dom}f,G(f)\rangle$, and use the fact that $|A|\ge 2$ to show that there is an injection from $\omega\times{}^\omega A$ into ${}^\omega A$. There’s a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse over it to see it.

> Further HINT: There are injections from $\omega$ into ${}^\omega A$ and from ${}^\omega A\times{}^\omega A$ into ${}^\omega A$.

Comment: For some reason, these sorts of questions finding injections and the such are really difficult for me. But I think I've come up with something, though I'm not sure it's right. Define the injection $g: \omega \rightarrow {}^{\omega}2$ as follows: $g(n)(x) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if } x \leq n\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}.$
Then $\omega \times {}^{\omega}A \preccurlyeq \omega \times {}^{\omega}2 \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}A \times {}^{\omega}A$ (since $2 \leq |A|$)...

Comment: So now we have to find an injection between ${}^{\omega}A \times {}^{\omega}A$ and ${}^{\omega}A$. So consider the function $h(\langle f, f' \rangle)(x) = (f^{-1} \circ f')(x)$. This is an injection since distinct $f, f'$ will produce distinct outputs. So ${}^{\omega}A \times {}^{\omega}A \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}A$ and $\text{Sq}(A) \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}A$

Comment: I made a mistake above: I meant $\omega \times {}^{\omega}A \preccurlyeq {}^{\omega}2 \times {}^{\omega}A$

Comment: My solution seems very clunky to me and I'm wondering if I've overcomplicated things.

Comment: @mijucik: Your $g$ works fine. There are two problems with $h$: $f'(n)$ may not be in the domain of $f^{-1}$, and $f^{-1}$ need not be a function. Remember, $f$ and $f'$ are simply sequences in $A$; try interlacing them.

Comment: That's where I had the most trouble actually. I thought at first about doing something like $h(\langle f, f' \rangle)(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if $x$ is odd}\\
f'(x) & \text{if $x$ is even}
\end{cases}
$
but then I realized that it's possible for it not to be an injection.

Comment: So I've been struggling on how I might interweave these two functions for a while in a unique way.

Comment: @mijucik: It **is** an injection. It’s even a bijection: given $\langle a_n:n\in\omega\rangle\in{}^\omega A$ we can reconstruct its preimage $\langle f,f'\rangle$: $f(n)=x_{2n+1}$, and $f'(n)=x_{2n}$.

Comment: @mijucik: Oops: change all of those $x$s to $a$s.

Comment: Wait nevermind. My example doesn't work. Let me think about this more...

Comment: @mijucik: I’m sorry, I misread your $h$. What I had in mind was that $h(\langle f,f'\rangle)(2n)=f'(n)$ and $h(\langle f,f'\rangle)(2n+1)=f(n)$ for all $n\in\omega$. Compare this with the inverse in my last comment. (I have to shut down now, but I’ll be back tomorrow.)

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: I know you've shut down for the night, but I just want to let you know that I think I understand it now! It's amazing that you are willing to take time out of your day to help someone like me understand concepts and solve problems. It really helps prevent me from getting discouraged in my studies of pure mathematics, which have honestly contained the hardest material I've ever learned (especially coming from computational courses in high school). So thank you again!

Comment: @mijucik: Excellent!  You’re very welcome.  Yes, the step from computational mathematics to abstract theory is a pretty big one, and what you’re studying well towards the abstract end.